# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. When having 2 gpu on the notebook

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I'm trying to install nvidia drivers for my notebook Lenovo Legion. My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX3060 and the last driver is 470. So I tried different ways to install the driver via downloading the driver (.run) from official NVIDIA site, from Software&Update, installing from terminal. But when try:

```
nvidia-smi
```

Got the error:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I think that the problem is that I have 2 GPUs in the notebook. I run:

```
sudo lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
```

The result is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a60] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3f80]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9a03] (rev 05)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2560] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3f80]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:228e] (rev a1)
```

Another thing when I reboot Ubuntu (18.04) it can not start. There appears the message:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks
```

Then I pres Ctrl + Shift + F3:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

After that the notebook starts.
When it have been started I change the main gpu to nvidia:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

The error is the same when trying `nvidia-smi`
So the question is how to handle with drivers for 2 GPUs on a PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was the problem in kernel version it was 5.4 but should be 5.10 and above. So kernel should be upgraded.